# Привет всем. я хочу создать бота в дискорде (на python) который повторяет сообщения, но не знаю как это сделать. пожалуйста помогите

Tags: python, discord, бот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот отрывок из моего кода, я не знаю что вставить в await message.reply и ещё не знаю что добавить в if message.content
а вот сам код:
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content == [сюда я не знаю что добавить]
await message.reply [я тоже не знаю]

Comment: Добрый день, лучше код вставлять текстом, а не картинкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

message это переменная со всеми данными сообщения, а message.content это текст сообщения

а if ниже лишний, так как пустое сообщение нельзя отправить.

```
if message.content == ""
```

вот правильный код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.reply(message.content)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое